# Boot problem on an HP Mini 1000

Tags: boot, live-usb

I recently acquired an HP Mini 1000 that had been purged of the operating system.  There is no CD, only USB ports.  I downloaded ubuntu 12.04 onto a flash drive, stuck it in the notebook, told it to boot from the USB and got a black screen "No bootable partiton in table".  How do I use ubuntu to boot my conputer.  Thanks.

Comment: How did you write the ISO to the USB stick?